# Coffeescript if condition for date

Tags: date, if-statement, coffeescript

This is my 1st mini project using coffeescript dcaf.

Im currently doing some function in coffeescript, my roadblock is i cant compare 2 dates on if statement. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript (and also in CoffeeScript) the comparison operators (`<`,`<=`,`==`,`>=`,`>`,`!=`) are overloaded for the `Date` object.

Hence you can use something like this (in plain JavaScript):

```js
var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = new Date();
if (d1 < d2) {
  console.log("D1 is strictly before D2");
}
```

or like this (in CoffeeScript):

```coffee
d1 = new Date()
d2 = new Date()
if d1 < d2
  console.log "D1 is strictly before D2"
```

In both cases the underlying implementation is equivalent to a numeric comparison of the "epoch time" representation of the Date object - number of milliseconds since midnight (00:00:00) 1 January 1970 UTC - the same value returned by the `getTime()` method. So `d1.getTime() < d2.getTime()` would be an alternative way to express that comparison if you want to be more explicit about what is being compared.